Powershell script to get IIS app pool recycling time from servers
I got the cmd below from the following post
Get Specific Recycling Time For IIS With PowerShell
Get-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool -Name recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.collection

Which outputs

value          : 04:14:00


Attributes     : {value}


ChildElements  : {}


ElementTagName : add


Methods        :


Schema         : Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElementSchema

However, it gives me the entire array when all i want is the 04:14:00 I've tried piping that to Select-Object -expandproperty with no luck
I've tried using Get-IISAppPool also which would be great for multiple servers, but again, I can't figure out how to get simply the recycle time.
Ultimately I need to get the recycle time of about 10 app pools on hundreds of servers. The only real output I want is $servername, $apppoolname & $recycletime
Can anyone point me to how to get simply the recycle time?
I'll probably do something like
$recycletime= Get-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\AppPools\$apppool -Name recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.collection    <=== don't know how to solve for the time only


I can wrap it all in an invoke-command because I think I'll need to import Webadministration tools on each node,  but again, it's getting only the Value that I can't solve.
Any help appreciated.

Which version of IIS / Windows are you running? Strangely running your first query on IIS 10, Server 2022 doesn't give me any output. However, tweaking the query slight
Import-Module WebAdministration
(Get-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\\AppPools\DefaultAppPool -Name recycling.periodicRestart | Select-Object -ExpandProperty time).toString()

Gives me that value in a usable way.
Note, it also works if you run :
Get-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\\AppPools\DefaultAppPool -Name recycling.periodicRestart | Select-Object time

where it outputs the heading, but if you add -ExpandProperty then you need to .toString() the entire thing, otherwise it outputs all the individual timespan elements, eg Days, Hours, Minutes etc, TotalDays, TotalHours etc.
-- EDIT --
OK, so the above code retrieves the "Regular Time intervals in Minutes" value, but to retrieve the "Specific Times" value you need.
(Get-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool -Name recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.collection).Value.ToString()

as with the above code you need to include .ToString() to just retrieve the time value not the individual time elements.

I have IIS 10 (server 2019).
Thanks for the suggestions, however it should return 04:14:00 but instead returns 1.05:00:00 (both cmds do this)--
also, did you mean to use "Get-ItemProperty?" Your cmds say "Get-Property" (I presume a typo

Oops, good point, have corrected typo. 1.05:00:00 would be the expected result if it's still using the default as I get the same value on my test box. Within the IIS UI, Application Pools > DefaultAppPool > Recycling > Regular Time Interval (minutes), mine shows as 1740, which equates to 1.05:00:00. Is yours different to that, or are you after a different value from elsewhere within IIS?

Thanks again for replying :)
The 1740 is the interval, yes. In the IIS gui, that field is called "Regular Time intervals in Minutes" (1740) but  the field I want is called "Specific Times" and it is 4:14am (also seen in OP in the output array) . It's the 4:14am that I need to be able to grab via script. I could probably parse the xml that contains this data, but it seems there should be an easier way to get this.

Ahhh got it. IIS only returns a value for that if one is configured... which is why I got nothing. Have set one now and determined what's needed. See latest update to my answer above.

That's the magic I've been looking for @keith! Thank you so much!
